# Comma Usage in a List of Locations in Same Region

Tags: punctuation, commas

We know that in City/State pairs you use a comma. But how would you punctuate a list of cities in the same country/region?

For example, saying:

> *He visited Trenton, New Jersey and Springfield, New Jersey.*

sounds clunky. Would the following be accurate?

> *He visited Trenton and Springfield, New Jersey*

Would it be considered ambiguous?

Comment: You can use the semicolon to separate list items that contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

In city-state pairs in the middle of a sentence, the state is set off with commas; it is a style error merely to use one comma between the city and state.

> Abilene, Texas, was named after Abilene, Kansas, which in turn was named after a city in the Bible.

No matter how many thousand times Wikipedia authors and [others](https://ask.metafilter.com/239830/When-did-become-OK-to-drop-the-comma-after-a-state) ignore this rule, it is still included in major style guides, such as AP or Chicago (16th ed., 6.17). The rational is that the state name functions as an appositive: Abilene, the one in Texas, and Abilene, the one in Kansas.

So your “clunky” sentence should read:

> He visited Trenton, New Jersey, and Springfield, New Jersey.

Or to reduce the clunkiness:

> He visited two New Jersey cities: Trenton and Springfield.
>
> He visited Trenton and Springfield, both in New Jersey.

or something similar.